Cross product of a vector field with its own conjugate
I have data of a 2D velocity field
$$
\textbf{V}(x,y,t)=V_x\hat{x} + V_y\hat{y}
$$
so that $V_x(x,y,t)$ and $V_y(x,y,t)$ are two separate 2D matrices on the (x,y) plane. How do I compute
$$
\textrm{Im}(\textbf{V}^*\times \textbf{V}) ?
$$
I tried to get a complex analytic form using a Hilbert transform on the real values of $V_x(x,y)$ and $V_y(x,y)$, got the complex conjugate, and proceeded with the usual cross product operation (all of this done through a computer program):
$$
\textrm{Im}(\textbf{V}^*\times \textbf{V}) = \textrm{Im}(V^{'*}_xV^{'}_y - V^{'}_xV^{'*}_y)
$$
the primes now indicating that the velocities are in complex form.
I'm not sure if using a Hilbert transform was necessary, or if it was, whether it should have been applied in 2D space or in time. I'm expecting the final result to be directed along the z-axis, but the resulting distribution is not what I expected, which should be similar to the result when getting the curl of the velocity field $\nabla\times\textbf{V}$. I also need their connection with each other. Thanks.
